# What 's wrong with VS2012 and Performance Analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to do some perf. analysis on a piece of code that is dog slow... I start VS2012 Premium as Admin, load my solution and the go to 'Analyze - Launch Performance Wizard' Immediately I am shown a dialog that says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'VSPerfReader.DLL' or one of its dependencies.
```

Awesome! The file is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
```

I can start Windows Performance Analyzer (standalone) from 'start' just fine btw.

Comment: Is the DLL on your path? When I look at my environment it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same issue, adding the following line to my system path variable and restarting visual studio did the trick.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools

Credit to Ade Miller in the comment for the solution.

Comment: Worked for VS2013 also (path would have "12.0") -- I think I was cleaning out the paths because it was getting too full and accidentally wiped it out a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Same instructions as Ryan Taylor above but with a visual. My issue was with Visual Studio 2013 (after installing VS2015 SP1). The value I entered the new path variable is below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
```

[image: VS2013 Path Fix]