# VSPerfReader.dll file could not load VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, every time I try to close Visual Studio 2013 it gives me this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCjzL.png - "Could not load file or assembly 'VSPerfReader.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specific module could not be found.

I a newbie at this stuff so please try not assume previous knowledge of things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you try to locate the file (probably in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools`) and add it to system path

credit [What 's wrong with VS2012 and Performance Analyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252599/what-s-wrong-with-vs2012-and-performance-analyzer)

Comment: Hi - what is meant by "Adding the following line to my system path variable"?

I was able to locate the file.

Comment: In system properties, select Environment Variables, then under System Variables, you will see an item by the name of 'PATH'. Double click on this, and copy the path to the dll. Be care full not to delete existing entries. Add the new path to the end of the string. Use a ';' to as the seperator

Comment: Awesome! Done.

Thank you so much

Comment: Did sense thank you, but Visual Studio restart was needed for me.